# Problems with repeater controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having lots of trouble understanding how repeaters are supposed to work and how I'm supposed to use them. Basically, I have a label, a set of image buttons, and a div within a repeater. When you click on the button, I want to populate the div that was created with these repeaters (so a different div for each iteration of the repeater).

It seems so simple, yet I can't get anything to work. Please help me!

Here is some of my code if that helps.

(my data source)

```
<asp:sqldatasource runat="server" id="dtsSpecialNotes" connectionstring="connection string" providername="System.Data.SqlClient"> /asp:sqldatasource
```

(my repeater)

```
<asp:Repeater id="rptSpecialNotes" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

(some code behind, I have a method to populate the repeater called on page load)

```
rptSpecialNotes.DataSource = dtsSpecialNotes
rptSpecialNotes.DataBind()

Dim imbMotion As New ImageButton 
Dim imbAttachments As New ImageButton

imbMotion.ImageUrl = "images/controls/Exclaim.png" 
imbMotion.Width = "40"  
imbMotion.Height = "40" 
imbMotion.AlternateText = "Add Motion" 
imbMotion.ID = "imbMotion" & listSpecialNotesCounter
imbAttachments.ImageUrl = "images/controls/Documents.png"
imbAttachments.Width = "40"
imbAttachments.Height = "40"
imbAttachments.AlternateText = "Add Document"
imbAttachments.ID = "imbAttachments" & listSpecialNotesCounter

rptSpecialNotes.Controls.Add(lblTitle) 
rptSpecialNotes.Controls.Add(imbMotion)
```

Here are the problems I'm having:

1. I can't get the repeater to iterate. It's only firing off once and then stops.
2. I can't get a label with the repeater data source's Subject (a field in my database) to appear.

I really appreciate any help. I just can't grasp these repeater controls.

Comment: This is not ASP classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is populate your repeater using the `ItemDataBound` event as opposed to going through the item collection. That will be called for each of the items that are in the collection you assigned to the `DataSource`.

This is what I do when working with repeater data binding and the ItemDataBound event, I'll use a list of news items for this example:

```
' Bind my collection to the repeater
Private Sub LoadData()
    Dim newsList As List(Of News) = dao.GetNewsList()
    rptrNews.DataSource = newsList
    rptrNews.DataBind()
End Sub

' Every item in the data binded list will come through here, to get the item it will be the object e.Item.DataItem
Protected Sub rptrNews_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        ' Get the current item that is being data bound
        Dim news As News = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, News)

        ' Then get all the controls that are within the <ItemTemplate> or other sections and populate them with the correct data, in your case it would be an image
        Dim ltlHeadline As Literal = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("ltlHeadline"), Literal)
        Dim ltlContent As Literal = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("ltlContent"), Literal)

        ltlHeadline.Text = news.Headline
        ltlContent.Text = news.Teaser
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could do it all in the Markup Code and only assign the datasource and call data bind in the code behind. To achieve this you could define your ItemTemplate as follows (again with the news e.g.):

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td><%#Container.DataItem("Headline")%></td>
    <td><%#Container.DataItem("Teaser")%></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That's not working for me. The dim news as News line, and the Dim newslist lines, come up with errors.

What I'm going to do is start on a blank page. Nothing on it. What is my first step...

Comment: I've only provided example code, you will have to tailor it to meet your requirements. I used a News object as an example, which won't be defined in your context. You'll have to use your data source.

Comment: Obviously it's just an example, but using a datasource isn't solving the problem. Thank you very much for trying though.